# Confirm delete javascript, php

Tags: javascript, php, confirm

I am using a simple way to have confirmation box when deleting a record, problem here is I couldn't find where to place `header` code for redirecting to some other page after deletion. I have placed it after executing query and get this error

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...

and I am not redirected to required page, but somehow on reloading page record wasn't there it was deleted.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$que=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM blogs WHERE blogs_id = :blogId");
$que->execute(array(':blogId'=>$blogId));
header("location:front.php");
}

<form method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")" />
</form>
```

Comment: Don't use header to redirect to other page use javascript window.location
``
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$que=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM blogs WHERE blogs_id = :blogId");
$que->execute(array(':blogId'=>$blogId));
?>
<script>window.location ='front.php';</script>
<?php } ?>
``

Comment: Rahul is mistaken. `header` is preferred. First make sure that there is no other output before sending the header (including any whitespace). Second, issue an `exit;` immediately after the header, or the rest of the script will continue to be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
header("front.php");
```

with

```
echo "<script> window.location='front.php';</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use meta refresh tag instead of header to redirect the page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `header("location:front.php");` instead of `header("front.php");`//but before header there should not be any echo or print otherwise it will not redirect.

your input for confirmation is wrong change it to this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" onclick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")' />
```

Comment: @bɪˈɡɪnə are you getting confirmation box.because as per your html you should not get.